# standalone ssl web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I published a standalone web service with java in a `http://my-IP/` and it works.

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Publisher
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        Endpoint.publish("http://172.16.58.13/", new TicketQueryImpl());
        System.out.println("UP");

    }
}
```

now I want to make it in SSL and publish it on `https://my-IP/`.

I searched a lot but i didn't find any good sample or help. most of them were not for **standalone** and used `Tomcat` or other servers. any body could help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL is a really complicated beast (from a programming side of things). Why not using something like nginx or Apache of your webservice proxying the requests? i.e. It gets an SSL connection requests, and forwards to your webservice listening in port 80.

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl; # Listen to SSL connections
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    server_name         my-IP.com www.my-IP.com;
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log main;
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/example.com.cache.log cache;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:80; # Forward requests to your webservice
    }
    Include     /etc/nginx/proxy.conf; # Proxy configuration
}
```

See also http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html for more information on configuring SSL server correctly.

Comment: I didn't used nginx,I downloaded it. how could i use this code with that?

Comment: This will be the definition of a site. For example, for nginx in Linux you will have to add a file containing this definition in /etc/nginx/sites-available and then symlink it in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled (i.e. `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site-name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site-name` and then restart nginx. Or maybe just modify default site and restart nginx.